# No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’. Debug.trace() error

Tags: haskell

```
import Debug.Trace
data Tree a = Nil | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)   deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Foldable Tree where
    foldr _ ini Nil = ini
    foldr f ini (Branch l x r) = trace (show x) (foldr f (f x (foldr f ini r)) l)
```

```
• No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘show’
  Possible fix:
    add (Show a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        foldr :: forall a b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
• In the first argument of ‘trace’, namely ‘(show x)’
  In the expression: trace (show x) (foldr f (f x (foldr f ini r)) l)
  In an equation for ‘foldr’:
      foldr f ini (Branch l x r)
        = trace (show x) (foldr f (f x (foldr f ini r)) l)
```

I don't understand what's the problem is. I will be very grateful for your help

Comment: There is no guarantee that `x::a` is showable. What if we fold over a tree of functions (or any other non-showable type)? Unfortunately, I can't see any workaround -- you can not use `show x` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `foldr` must work for `Tree a` with *any* element-type `a`, including types such as `[Integer] -> Double` which you can't possibly show. Thus it is not possible to use `show x` within the definition. It doesn't matter that this is just for debugging purposes and you want to debug only, say, the `Tree Int` case – the compiler needs to have the instance available for all types it could possibly be used with.

As a workaround, you can implement the function first as a `Show`-restricted version, and only after debugging change it into a `Foldable` method without the `trace` parts.

```
foldrTree :: Show a => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> Tree a -> b
foldrTree _ ini Nil = ini
foldrTree f ini (Branch l x r) = trace (show x) (foldrTree f (f x (foldr f ini r)) l)
```